# Remove P tags from Advanced Custom Fields images

Tags: wordpress, image, tags

I'm using WordPress 4.2.2 and every time I add an image to the WYSIWYG it wraps the output image in a paragraph tag. I need to strip out these tags. Everything I seem to find online is from 2011 plus it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried putting things in the functions.php like:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
  return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Nothing seems to work. How can I accomplish this.

BTW I am using ACF Pro's WYSIWYG and JointsWP starter theme and my images ARE NOT wrapped in a link tag if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why not disable `wpautop` completely?

Comment: I have tried: remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); but that doesn't work I think because I am not using the_content(); im using an Advanced Custom Fields wysiwyg [ the_field('myField'); ] right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('p > img').unwrap();
```

nuff said.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Advanced Custom Fields, you should be able to use `get_field()`, but turn off formatting:

```
echo get_field('myField', $post->ID, false);
```

Read more about [`get_field()` in the ACF Docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).

You can also remove the ACF implementation of `wpautop` by doing the following in **functions.php**:

```
remove_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Comment: Actually this is stripping out all the p tags even in the paragraphs where I need them to be wrapped in a paragraph tag. I just want to strip it from the images

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - I added this in my functions file to get rid of the p tags around images when using Advanced Custom Fields WYSIWYG:

```
// gets rid of p tags around images when using the WYSIWYG advanced custom fields

function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```